# Exporting spatial object in mysql to shapefile with spatial reference

Tags: ogr2ogr, mysql, osgeo4w

Info: Win7, MySQL 5.x and OSGEO4W 1.11

To import a shapeafile to MySQL I use this ogr2ogr command:

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:gis,user=root,password=password C:\posto_pianco.shp -nln pianco_post -a_srs EPSG:29194 -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM
```

To export from MySQL to shapefile I use this:

```
ogr2ogr out_shapes MYSQL:gis,user=root,password=password
```

The Problem: The shapefile files exported have no spatial reference, how to resolve this?

Summary of layer:

```
Layer name: pianco_post
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-37.928100, -7.204400) - (-37.928100, -7.204400)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["SAD69 / UTM zone 24S",
    GEOGCS["SAD69",
        DATUM["South_American_Datum_1969",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1967 Modified",6378160,298.25,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7050"]],
            TOWGS84[-57,1,-41,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6618"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4618"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-39],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","29194"]]
FID Column = OGR_FID
Geometry Column = SHAPE
objectid: Real (9.0)
codigo: Real (9.0)
nome: String (35.0)
altitude: Real (19.11)
longitude: Real (19.11)
latitude: Real (19.11)
disponibil: String (31.0)
area_drena: Real (9.0)
```

Comment: Quick fix is to use the same -a_srs EPSG:29194 option when you write out the shapefiles. However, it should not be necessary because GDAL should find the SRID from the MySQL database. Now it fails for some reason. What does ogrinfo report about that table in MySQL? Summary is enough (-so option).

Comment: @user30184 I edited the question.

Comment: @user30184 the osgeo4w is so unstable, now works, I don't make any changes.

Comment: You mean that the problem disappeared and you get now shapefiles with correct .prj file? Ogrinfo should then report the same projection for the shapefile and MySQL table.